# Cannot save new entries

Tags: channel-entries, url-title

Please help me Im going a bit crazy with a simple problem.

I am trying to use the current time for my URL title so they are no easily found, I had it working but it isn't anymore and I cant work out why. It will post a new entry if I just allow it to use the title as the URL title.

Any ideas? Its driving mad, as it must be something so simple but I cant see it :)

```
{exp:channel:form channel="Channel" return="/test/{segment_2}" url_title="{segment_2}"}

    <div class="large-6 columns">
        <label for="title">title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100">
    </div>

    <label for="url_title">urltitle</label>
    <input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{title}{current_time}" size="50" maxlength="100">                          

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">

{/exp:channel:form}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at what {current_time} renders out - possibly it's invalid as a URL title?  Try {current_time format="%i%H%d%n"}

Comment: Thanks Peter, I discovered that I was only using numbers for the URL title ans this is not allowed. I changed it and it worked a treat.